# Python object type changed after assign, is it a bug?

Tags: python, json, rabbitmq

The content string of the boy variable is received from [AMQP](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) message queue. It is a json string. It will be changed to python object by the standard json library

```
body         = {"TestPlanName": "DemoPlan", "ReplyTo": "Reply", "Drivers": [1, 2, 3], "Cmd": "Start", "IsResetTool": true, "TestCycleId": 1}
logging.debug('Received message body: %s' % body)
msg          = json.loads(body)
for key, value in msg.items():
    logging.debug('key %s, type %s, value %s' % (key, type(value), value))
    logging.debug('key %s, type %s, value %s' % (key, type(value), msg[key]))

logging.debug('Parsed json object %s' % msg)

cmd          = msg[EXECUTOR.CMD],
drivers      = msg[EXECUTOR.DRIVERS], 
testCycleId  = msg[EXECUTOR.TEST_CYCLE_ID], 
testPlanName = msg[EXECUTOR.TEST_PLAN_NAME]
replyTo      = msg[EXECUTOR.REPLY_TO]

logging.debug('Parsed result type %s value %s' % (type(cmd          ), cmd          ))
logging.debug('Parsed result type %s value %s' % (type(drivers      ), drivers      ))
logging.debug('Parsed result type %s value %s' % (type(testCycleId  ), testCycleId  ))
logging.debug('Parsed result type %s value %s' % (type(dmType       ), dmType       ))
```

Out put log files:

```
DEBUG msg:Received message body: {"TestPlanName": "DemoPlan", "ReplyTo": "Reply", "Drivers": [1, 2, 3], "Cmd": "Start", "DMType": "DM2", "IsResetTool": true, "TestCycleId": 1}
DEBUG msg:key TestPlanName, type <type 'unicode'>, value DemoPlan
DEBUG msg:key TestPlanName, type <type 'unicode'>, value DemoPlan
DEBUG msg:key ReplyTo, type <type 'unicode'>, value Reply
DEBUG msg:key ReplyTo, type <type 'unicode'>, value Reply
DEBUG msg:key Drivers, type <type 'list'>, value [1, 2, 3]
DEBUG msg:key Drivers, type <type 'list'>, value [1, 2, 3]
DEBUG msg:key Cmd, type <type 'unicode'>, value Start
DEBUG msg:key Cmd, type <type 'unicode'>, value Start
DEBUG msg:key IsResetTool, type <type 'bool'>, value True
DEBUG msg:key IsResetTool, type <type 'bool'>, value True
DEBUG msg:key TestCycleId, type <type 'int'>, value 1
DEBUG msg:key TestCycleId, type <type 'int'>, value 1
DEBUG msg:Parsed json object {u'TestPlanName': u'DemoPlan', u'ReplyTo': u'Reply', u'Drivers': [1, 2, 3], u'Cmd': u'Start', u'DMType': u'DM2', u'IsResetTool': True, u'TestCycleId': 1}
DEBUG msg:Before call ScriptDispatcher.ScriptDispatcher_CleanStopedExecutors args: () kwargs:{}     
DEBUG msg:After call ScriptDispatcher.ScriptDispatcher_CleanStopedExecutors  return: None
DEBUG msg:Parsed result type <type 'tuple'> value (u'Start',)
DEBUG msg:Parsed result type <type 'tuple'> value ([1, 2, 3],)
DEBUG msg:Parsed result type <type 'tuple'> value (1,)
DEBUG msg:Parsed result type <type 'unicode'> value DM2
DEBUG msg:Parsed result type <type 'unicode'> value DemoPlan
DEBUG msg:Parsed result type <type 'unicode'> value Reply
```

After assignment the item of the msg dictionary, the unicode string type `u'Start'` is changed to a tuple, the list `[1,2,3]` is changed to `([1,2,3],)` and the number 1 changed to (1,)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have trailing commas on your assignments:

```
cmd          = msg[EXECUTOR.CMD],
drivers      = msg[EXECUTOR.DRIVERS], 
testCycleId  = msg[EXECUTOR.TEST_CYCLE_ID],
```

So really those are tuples (by accident, I'm assuming).

Comment: Yes, I have continue worked more than 16 hours in each day during during this month. It's really a stupid mistake. Thank you very much for the quick response!

Comment: It's a classic mistake, I've definitely been there. You should take a break though, it's not healthy to work so much - absolutely been there too :)

Answer (score 4):

You have trailing commas in your assignment ie  `cmd          = msg[EXECUTOR.CMD],` <--  That trailing comma will make it a tuple remove those and it will act as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's a bug, but in your code, not in Python.

In Python a tuple is defined by a comma. Your assignments all end with commas, therefore they are tuples.

Instead of

```
cmd          = msg[EXECUTOR.CMD],
```

do

```
cmd          = msg[EXECUTOR.CMD]
```

Comment: x_x... thanks you very much, it's really a stupid mistake... also it waste me several hours!